# d3 dates times and integers in table

Tags: d3.js, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable, datetime-format

Using the [sortable table](http://bl.ocks.org/AMDS/4a61497182b8fcb05906) by [Mingsong Hu](https://bl.ocks.org/AMDS) I am displaying times and integers in some columns.

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/dxxpkhj7/1/)

I can get the time and integers to display, but is this the best way to do it? I feel it's a real hack!

The sortability of the table's columns is not working correctly. I think this is due to needing to be able to sort on times or alphabetically or on integers.

```
   var rows = table.append('tbody').selectAll('tr')
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('tr');
    rows.selectAll('td')
      .data(function(d) {
        return titles.map(function(k) {
          return {
            'category': d[k],
            'name': k
          };
        });
      }).enter()
      .append('td')
      .attr('data-th', function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        if (timeformat(d.category) == "NaN:NaN") {
          return d.category
        } else if (timeformat(d.category) == "00:00") {
          return +d.category
        } else {
          return timeformat(d.category)
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it so that certain columns sort alphabetically and the rest numerically. Also I have fixed the time format for the display of times using typeof()=="object"

The updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofey/dxxpkhj7/2/) also on [github](https://github.com/shanegibney/d3-v4-sortable-table) and [demo](https://shanegibney.github.io/d3-v4-sortable-table/) on gh-pages.

Here's the new code,

```
 var sortAscending = true;
    var table = d3.select('#page-wrap').append('table');
    var titles = d3.keys(data[0]);
    var titles = ["raceplace", "name", "club", "clocktime", "category", "handicap", "racetime", "timeplace", "points"]
    var headers = table.append('thead').append('tr')
      .selectAll('th')
      .data(titles).enter()
      .append('th')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d
      })
      .on('click', function(d) {
        headers.attr('class', 'header');
        if (d == "name" || d == "club" || d == "category") { //these keys sort alphabetically
          // sorting alphabetically");
          if (sortAscending) {
            rows.sort(function(a, b) {
              return d3.ascending(a[d], b[d]);
            });
            sortAscending = false;
            this.className = 'aes';
          } else {
            rows.sort(function(a, b) {
              return d3.descending(a[d], b[d]);
            });
            sortAscending = true;
            this.className = 'des';
          }
        } else {
          if (sortAscending) {
            //all other keys sort numerically including time
            rows.sort(function(a, b) {
              return b[d] - a[d];
            });
            sortAscending = false;
            this.className = 'aes';
          } else {
            rows.sort(function(a, b) {
              return a[d] - b[d];
            });
            sortAscending = true;
            this.className = 'des';
          }
        }
      });

    var rows = table.append('tbody').selectAll('tr')
      .data(data).enter()
      .append('tr');
    rows.selectAll('td')
      .data(function(d) {
        return titles.map(function(key, i) {
          return {
            'value': d[key],
            'name': d
          };
        });
      }).enter()
      .append('td')
      .attr('data-th', function(d) {
        return d.name;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        //console.log("typeof(" + d.value + "): " + typeof(d.value));
        if (typeof(d.value) == "object") {
          //console.log("Yippee it's an object");
          return timeformat(d.value)
        } else {
          return d.value
        }
      });
```